# Spark Dataframe Dynamic DataType Cast based on Other Column

Tags: apache-spark, dynamic, casting, user-defined-functions

We're getting a generic data feed where this is a value and datatype in 2 columns. Obviously for a generic solution I want to pass the column value into the cast rather than explicitly cast everything based on other reference data.

I tried this but am getting an exception. So 2 questions really is the above possible? Why is my solution giving an exception?

I'm trying a declare a UDF that passes the type back.

```
def dynamiccast(datatype: String) : DataType = {

  var b:DataType = null
  datatype match {
    case "INT" => b = IntegerType
    case "STRING" => b = StringType
    case "BOOLEAN" => b = BooleanType
  }
  b
}

val castUDF = udf[DataType, String](dynamiccast)
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType is not supported
```

Cheers

Comment: add all remain data type lie this  `case "string" => StringType
      case "bigint" => LongType
      case "int" => IntegerType
      case "double" => DoubleType
      case "date" => TimestampType
      case "boolean" => BooleanType
      case "timestamp" => TimestampType`

Comment: how does that solve the exception!? The exception is to do with the fact that datatype doesn't support schema for reflection which I assume the UDF needs